# Using media queries how to get a form to be the width of the screen & its labels/elements to be at full width when the screen is less than 600px wide?

Tags: html, css, forms

This is the code I wrote, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
@media screen and (width < 600px) {
.form {display:max-width;}

@media screen and (width < 600px) {
 div {
    display:max-width;
  }
```

I chose div because all form labels/inputs/elements are inside of divs.

Answer (score 0):

`@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` is the rule you looking for. Media queries don't use `<` or `>` conditions but `max-` and `min-`

Then you should combine bot rules. `max-width` is not a legit value (especially not for the display property). Simply use `auto` to occupy all available space.

Last but not least, by sizing the div at the max available width you will not size the containing elements to be the same width. YOu need to specifically set them to `width: auto`

```css
@media only screen
  and (max-width: 600px) {
    .form,
    div > * {
      width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes they use in level 4 https://caniuse.com/?search=media

Comment: level 4 was implemented in July 2022 and still has poor support (Firefox and Chrome for desktop))